# Query MySql database in Docker

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have a docker container with mariadb, and have created a database `my_db` in it (through an external script in a different container). How can I run SQL queries on `my_db` now from the command line? I just want to do

`select * from my_table`

from the terminal that is running the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to exec into the container and execute the query using the mysql client, given the clients installed.

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME mysql -p -e 'QUERY' DB_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the commandline tool installed in the app container,

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.7 -u admin -pxyz -P 10202
```

This allows for the docker instance to be on another machine (192...) and with a special port (-P ...), etc.  (I have multiple docker containers; that one is for MariaDB 10.2.2.)

Comment: What is `-pxyz` for?

Comment: -p, no space, is how you can put the password on the commandline.